# Idiom or word to say to someone who is talking without proof or data

Tags: idioms, american-english, vocabulary

I am working in the IT field. We faced an issue and hired a consultant to resolve that. Consultant gave us some generic recommendation which is not based on any data and will not resolve our issue.

Do you have any word or idiom in English to explain such situation?

Comment: The report is "not worth the paper it was written on." This is in several dictionaries but is more usually used to refer to a useless agreement.

Comment: _Caveat emptor_. 'We' should have specified what would constitute a satisfactory 'resolution'.

Comment: The consultant's conclusions were not [**substantiated**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/substantiate).

Comment: The title question is addressed at [What is a word or expression for a convenient and unsupported answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395166/word-or-expression-for-a-convenient-and-unsupported-answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a word or expression for a convenient and unsupported answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395166/what-is-a-word-or-expression-for-a-convenient-and-unsupported-answer)

Comment: Still trying best way to convey below through words...
Consultant who is providing solution without analyzing Data or without providing any proof

Comment: 'Unsupported' is often used for such assertions on ELU. 'Arrogations' is a noun that fits, but it is fairly rare.

Answer (score 1):

You could say the contractor's recommendations are ***pulled from a hat***, like how a raffle winner might be selected - the recommendation has no rational basis or support, and is seemingly random.

One could also say the contractor is ***talking out of their ass***, which occurs when a person expounds upon a subject with seeming authority, although they don't actually know what they're talking about. Another common term for this is ***bullshitting***.

A way to express the utter uselessness of the recommendation is to remark ***"that and fifty cents will buy you a cup of coffee"***. Assuming a cup of coffee costs 50 cents (although not genreally true these days), the suggestion carries no value whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the contractor served up a **nothingburger**. From Lexico:

> **[nothingburger](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nothingburger)**: Something that is or turns out to be insignificant or lacking in substance.

A related possibility is **Where's the beef?** From Wikipedia:

> [**Where's the beef?**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where%27s_the_beef%3F#:%7E:text=%22%20Where%27s%20the%20beef%3F%20%22%20is%20a%20catchphrase,the%20substance%20of%20an%20idea%2C%20event%20or%20product.) is a catchphrase in the United States and Canada, introduced as a slogan for the fast food chain Wendy's in 1984. Since then it has become *an all-purpose phrase questioning the substance of an idea, event, or product*. [Emphasis mine]

Comment: Except that this terminology is being turned on its head by the trend towards vegetable-based burgers.

Comment: @HotLicks There is nothing in *nothingburger** that requires the burger to be meat-based rather than vegetable-based. With regard to the oft-used query "Where's the beef?" -- in this day and age one could say, "Where are the veggies?" Silly.

Answer (score 0):

This idiom might leave the consultant fuming afterward but you could say that he's "talking through his hat".